# Close any Bootstrap 3 popover with click on any buttons therein?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have an app that will have several popovers that uses the html of a hidden DIV.  This content may contain a button or buttons that will possibly do something in the app and close the popover, or just close the popover ("Cancel").  Like this:

[image]

What I'm looking for is a generic, extensible solution that I can apply to the button(s) to simply close the popover that contains them.

I don't want to wire this with anything specific to a particular button and/or popover.

I tried this and it does not work:
`<button class="btn btn-link btn-xs" data-toggle="popover">Cancel</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go this also works for tablet to tap outside the popover to hide it.

```
   //HIDES POPOVER ON TABLET WHEN CLICK OUTSIDE

 $('html').on('mouseup', function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).closest('.popover').length) {
        $('.popover').each(function(){
        $(this.previousSibling).popover('hide');
        });
     }
  });
```